# Do we need two initial conditions for a system of constant-coefficient differential equations where the eigenvalues are repeated?

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

For a systems of differential equations where the coefficients are constant, the general solution has the following form (where $x_1$ and $x_2$ are eigenvectors for $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$:

- $u(t) = C e^{\lambda_1 t} x_1 + Dt e^{\lambda_1 t} x_2$

To solve for variables $C$ and $D$, it seems we need at least two initial conditions: one at $u(0)$ and another at some arbitrary time $u(t)$. For example, $u(1)$. Is this true?

- Set $t=0$.
- $u(0) = C x_1 + 0$
- Solve for $C$.
- Plug $C$ back in and solve for $D$ when $t = 1$.

Comment: This appears to be quite impossible. With a basis solution containing $te^{λ_2t}$ there should also exist an independent basis solution containing only $e^{λ_2t}$. Or did you want to discuss the case $λ_1=λ_2$?

Comment: yes, my top @LutzLehmann

Comment: You need $Cx_1=u(t)|_{t=0}$ and $Dx_2=\frac{d}{dt}(u(t)e^{-\lambda_1t})|_{t=0}$.

Comment: So you only need one initial condition, and you evaluate the derivative at that condition?

Comment: Yes, you need the value of the function and its derivative at $0$.